# strcat on an std::string cast to a char*

Tags: c++

I found this (simplified) piece of code in our code base and it's leaving me feeling unpleasant. It either works, doesn't work, or is never called anyway. I would expect some buffer overflow, but when I try it in an online compiler it certainly doesn't work, but doesn't overflow either. I'm looking at the definition of `strcat` and it will write the source to the destination starting at its null terminator, but I am assuming in this scenario, the destination buffer (which was created as a `std::string`) should be too small..

```
#include <iostream>
#include "string.h"

using namespace std;

void addtostring(char* str){
    char str2[12] = "goodbye";
    strcat(str, str2);
}

int main()
{
    std::string my_string = "hello";
    addtostring((char*)my_string.c_str());

    cout << my_string << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What would be the actual behaviour of this operation?

Comment: The line `(char*)my_string.c_str()` is discarding a `const`. You are explicitly circumventing the type system to do something illegal that the type system is design to protect you from. `c_str()` returns a `const char *` because you aren't supposes to use it to modify the array it points.

Comment: You have undefined behavior. This is a kind of error where your code's behavior is not defined by the standard and it can do anything. You must not have any expectation regarding undefined behavior, including expecting a specific mode of failure or even expecting it to fail at all (it can appear to work according to your expectations).

Comment: It may even work according to your expectations, until after you've shipped the product, and then it may do something bad.  It may not seem possible, but that's undefined behavior for you.

Answer (score 10):

> What would be the actual behaviour of this operation?

The behavior is undefined.  First, [writing to any character through `c_str` is undefined behavior](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/string.accessors#3). Secondly, had you used `data` instead to get a `char*`, [overwriting the null terminator is also undefined behavior](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/string.accessors#6).  Lastly, both `c_str` and `data` only give you a pointer (`p`) that has a valid range of elements from `[p, p + size()]`.  Writing to any element outside that range is also undefined behavior.

If you want to modify the string you need to use the string's member/free functions to do so. Your function could be rewritten to

```
void addtostring(std::string& str){
    str += "goodbye";
}
```

and that will have well defined behavior.